# beanManager.fireEvent doesn't fire with OmniFaces 3.1

Tags: wildfly, cdi, omnifaces, jboss-weld

***** UPDATED *****

I have the following method in a Stateless Session Bean, deployed in an EAR on JBoss WildFly 12.0.0.Final which is called when the database is updated.

```
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@Inject 
private BeanManager beanManager;

public void onFoodsCosmeticsMedicinesChange(FoodsCosmeticsMedicines foodsCosmeticsMedicines) {
    logger.info(">>>>> onFoodsCosmeticsMedicinesChange beanManager = {}", beanManager);
    logger.info(">>>>> onFoodsCosmeticsMedicinesChange getBrand = {}", foodsCosmeticsMedicines.getBrand());

    beanManager.fireEvent(new PushEvent(foodsCosmeticsMedicines.getBrand()));
}
```

PushBean is a POJO, contained in the WAR:

```
import org.omnifaces.cdi.Push;
import org.omnifaces.cdi.PushContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class PushBean {

    /**
     *
     */
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    /**
     *
     */
    @Inject
    @Push(channel = "testChannel")
    private PushContext testChannel;

    /**
     *
     */
    public PushBean() {
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param pushEvent PushEvent
     */
    public void onPush(@Observes PushEvent pushEvent) {
        logger.info("***** onPersist pushEvent getMessage = {}", pushEvent.getMessage());
        logger.info("***** pushContext  = {}", testChannel);

        testChannel.send(pushEvent.getMessage());
    }
}
```

PushEvent:

```
public final class PushEvent {

    private final String message;

    public PushEvent(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

The OmniFaces 3.1 JAR is only in the WAR.

When the method 'onFoodsCosmeticsMedicinesChange' is called the console log shows:

> INFO  [com.notifywell.ejb.FoodsCosmeticsMedicinesEJB] (default task-4)
>   **onFoodsCosmeticsMedicinesChange beanManager = Weld BeanManager for
>   NOTiFYwell.ear/NOTiFYwellJAR.jar/ [bean count=38]** 
>   INFO[com.notifywell.ejb.FoodsCosmeticsMedicinesEJB] (default task-4)
>   **onFoodsCosmeticsMedicinesChange getBrand = BONNE MAMAN**

But the following statement:

```
beanManager.fireEvent(new PushEvent(foodsCosmeticsMedicines.getBrand()));
```

Doesn't appear to be executed as I do not see the PushBean method 'onPersist' in PushBean being executed:

```
public void onPush(@Observes PushEvent pushEvent) {
```

Deployed on WildFly 12.0.0.Final on MacOS using EE8.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are at least not posting a [mcve]. So it is difficult to try to reproduce (error prone) and hence nextvto impossible to debug or find a reason let alone a solution.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709475/is-it-possible-to-observe-a-cdi-event-inside-a-war-when-packaged-as-ear?

Comment: Where do you FIRE the event... in what class, yes a sessionbean but where is that in the EAR? And where is the PushEvent packaged? All sounds like you are running into the 'related' I posted above...

Comment: The Session Bean is in a JAR packaged with the WAR in the EAR. The PushEvent is in the JAR. This is standard EE packaging. I refer to the OmniFaces documentation see: http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/3.1/org/omnifaces/cdi/push/Socket.html#ejb

Comment: The post you refer to is over 5 years old & self-answered and contradicts the OmniFaces documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The above code works. 'Schoolboy error', I had a typo in my build and the 'PushBean.class' was being put in the wrong place in my WAR.

It should have been in:

```
WEB-INF/classes/PushBean.class
```

I now see my event being fired in the 'onPush' method of PushBean:

> 13:18:30,598 INFO  [com.notifywell.push.PushBean] (default task-1)
>   ***** onPush pushEvent getMessage = BONNE MAMAN